# C: mmap failed: No such device

Tags: c, memory-mapping

I'm trying to create a memory map using the c commands

```
  void* mem_map = mmap(NULL, 
                       sizeof(serverData),      //200000
                       PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                       MAP_SHARED, 
                       mem_map_fp, 
                       0);

  if(mem_map == MAP_FAILED){
    bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE, "mmap");
  }
```

The program compiles, but when trying to run the following error is produced:

```
mmap: No such device
```

To my understanding there is nothing wrong with the code which makes me suspect that the reason might be a little more complex. 
I'm running this linux version:

```
Linux ubuntu 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to allocate memory, so you should use the `MAP_ANON` or `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag, along with the standard arguments `-1` for the file descriptor and `0` for the offset, like so :

```
mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
```

Comment: No, the goal is to create a shared memory to be used by multiple processes,

Comment: I guess you just need to change `MAP_PRIVATE` to `MAP_SHARED` in my example then.